# How to accept only one decimal point in a datagridviewcell in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, decimal

Im using this code on a `bunifuTextbox` keypress event and it works perfectly fine:

```
               //accept only 3 decimal places
                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(quantitytextbox.Text, @"\d+(\.\d{3,3})") && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyChar == '.' && quantitytextbox.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                // Stop first char as a dot input
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            // only allow one decimal point
            if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMaterialTextbox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

can someone please tell me what to put inside this 'if' condition, because this is where the error occurs when im trying to use this code for my `datagridview` :

```
                // only allow one decimal point
            if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as /* I dont know what to put here*/).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

Comment: If your DGV is bound to a datasource, it will know the type and only allow valid entries all by itself

Comment: my dgv isn't bound to datasource sir. i dont know how to do it

Comment: Are you trying to detect if a cell contains “only one decimal point” or are you trying to detect if a cell contains a decimal number, because those are two different questions.

Comment: i want the cell to contain only one decimal point and up to 3 decimal places only.